# Unable to restore from backup - how to obtain old blog posts?

Tags: posts, theme-development, customization, multisite, migration

A little back story for context:

I was brought in to help fix an issue with a WordPress Theme Update & Migration gone horribly wrong. Long story short, when the guy that did the move finished the work he somehow 'lost' all the blog posts...*6 years worth of blogs posts.*

Luckily I was able *(from what I can tell)* find a full backup of the old website before it was migrated, in addition to a copy of the MySQL DB.

However, it seems that it was a multisite configuration - and after uploading all of the web files to a sub-domain, and replicating the DB (as best I can tell) the website is still not accessible.

I've pretty much given up on the idea of fully replicating the website as it was - I feel like I've tried everything. With that being said - the only thing that's really important to the customer are the blog posts.

My question is this: If I still have the original web files, is there some way to extract the blog data and inject it into the new WordPress website? If so, how would I go about doing that?

These types of issue(s) and/or troubleshooting is not something I have a lot of experience in - as i'm really just a front-end developer.

Any/all help is **greatly** appreciated!

(if more information is required to help - please let me know and I'll provide it ASAP)

Comment: of which migration are you talking about ? from were come the website ? and the backup files ?

Comment: @mmm The pervious person who did the website migration/upgrade. There was a website that had 6+ years of blog posts, but the website itself was very dated looking. So he was brought in to create a new WordPress Theme and migrate the website to a new reliable host. During the migration of the website - somehow the developer lost the data and couldn't upload the full site. But I seem to have been able to locate the old web files. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: and on the new host, the site use the same domain as the old host ?

Comment: What exactly does backup have? If it's copy of WP database you should able to claw posts out of it fine, though importing them would be a custom effort. It's strange that you can't just get old site up from full backup, but not enough details to day about that...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I would take.

1. Make a backup of the database backup and store it someplace safe
2. Find out what version of WordPress the site was running when the
   backup was done like this:

   - open the sql dump file in a text editor and search for db_version.
   - Use that value to find the corresponding WordPress version, [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions).
3. Install that [version of WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/) locally or on a dev site (subdomain or whatever)
4. Follow the [instructions for migrating](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs) a site to a new domain (i.e. localhost or dev.example.com)
5. Use the *WordPress/tools/export* tool to export the posts.
6. Import that .xml file into the new blog